# Firebase retrieve all data on app start

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have trouble finding any information using firebase documentation and google on how to retrieve all data on app start.

Let's assume, I want to get all the following data on app start without any event. and store in a ArrayList. Let's say `ArrayList<Quote>` and quote has three fields (int id, String text, String author).

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "text": "There are 1,411 tigers left in India.",
    "author": "NULL"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "text": "The Greek for \"left-handed\" also means \"better\".",
    "author": "NULL"
}]
```

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) there is a method called **onDataChange()** but, app is not changing any data. How to grab all data and store in `ArrayList<Quote>` which I can pass to custom adapter.

Comment: Reading from the doc, section "Value Events":  `onDataChange() [...]  This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Keeping Data Fresh

The Firebase Realtime Database synchronizes and stores a local copy of the data for active listeners. In addition, you can keep specific locations in sync.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

The client will automatically download the data at these locations and keep it in sync even if the reference has no active listeners. You can turn synchronization back off with the following line of code.

Refer this doc for more info; https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: where does it store the local copy? Is it reference-able? is it accessible?

Answer (score 2):

The `onDataChange()` method is called directly when the listener (`ValueEventListener` or `ChildEventListener`) is attached, so you don't need to do any changes to the data to trigger that method.

From the documentation [Firebase - Retrieve Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.